# Address to entity in symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hi I'm using symfony2 and I created a view and a entity for it.

The view entities are in the Entity/vu folder and when I address it like this it gives me the error:

Code:

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:GroupPermission')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p.id, p.group, p.permission,p.adminAccess, p.id as token ');
```

And the error:

```
Class 'Doobin\UserBundle\Entity\vu' does not exist
```

I also tried:

```
 $qb = $em->getRepository('UserBundle\vu:vu_u001_GroupPermission')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p.id, p.group, p.permission,p.adminAccess, p.id as token ');
```

And gives me this error:

```
 Unknown Entity namespace alias 'UserBundle/vu'.
```

How should I address that Entity?

Comment: Hello, the `Entity` folder should not contain views, this is the role of the controller.

Comment: Please show the code of your Entity, at least the start of the file, without all the methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In entity you have all getter and setters etc , like this

```
class Brand {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="brand")
     */
    protected $products;
}
```

For getting data from table or want to run query create a repository file 
like  BrandRepository in your entity folder 
and write like query

> public function findAllBrand() {  $query = $this->getEntityManager()
>   ->createQuery('SELECT b.id,b.name,b.image FROM ProjectNameAdminBundle:Brand b ORDER BY b.' .  $sort . ' ASC');
>
> try {   return $query->getResult();    } catch
>   (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
>           return "null";
>       }
>       }

and you can fetch this in controller easily .